# Why is extnValue in X.509 Extensions always encapsulated in an OCTET_STRING?

Tags: x509certificate, x509, pki, asn.1

I'm curious, and I was not able to find an explanation so far.

In RFC 5280 Extensions define the following:

```
   Extension  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        extnID      OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
        critical    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
        extnValue   OCTET STRING
                    -- contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value
                    -- corresponding to the extension type identified
                    -- by extnID
        }
```

What is the reason for defining the encapsulating OCTET_STRING for extnValue, instead of directly defining extnValue as the "DER encoding of an ASN.1 value corresponding to the extension type identified by extnID".

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an authoritative answer, but my thoughts are: this is because extension values may have arbitrary enclosing tags and can be defined in external modules:

[image]

Most extensions use `SEQUENCE`, but some are not, like in a given example, Subject Key Identifier is just another `OCTET_STRING`, Key Usages is a `BIT_STRING`. And in base type definition you have to use fixed tag to represent variable content (`ANY`).

In addition, parsers may not know how to parse particular extension, so they read it as octet string without having to dig deeper if extension type is unknown to parser.

update 13.02.2023 (based on comments):

> Regarding the type / tag, from my understanding, each different type can be easily identified by the leading tag byte, such as SEQUENCE=0x10, OCTET_STRING=0x04 or BIT_STRING=0x03

you cannot define the field with variable tag, because you introduce type ambiguity. That is, `extnValue ANY` field definition is not valid, because its type is indeterminate. When you define a type (in this case, it is `Extension` type), all fields must have deterministic tag.

Comment: Thanks. While I'm still digesting most of the answer, regarding specifically detecting unknown extensions, should this not happen based on OID?

Comment: Regarding the type / tag, from my understanding, each different type can be easily identified by the leading tag byte, such as SEQUENCE=0x10, OCTET_STRING=0x04 or BIT_STRING=0x03.
I didn't get the part about "base type definition". I'd imagine even if a custom extension specifies an "ANY" value, then whatever type is actually used will be present and can also be identified according to its tag.

Answer (score 2):

**extnValue** is what we call a specification hole.

It is just a container for whatever you want.

The receiver of the data will have to know how to understand it based on another specification (**extnID** is the way to find this specification)

The comment states that it contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value ... but it is only a comment.

As far as we are concerned, **extnValue** are just bytes and **OCTET STRING** is the best ASN.1 type to carry bytes (8bit).

In the past, there was a (terrible) type called **ANY** that was doing exactly this: carring bytes that represents an (unspecified) ASN.1 value. But it was deprecated in 1994 before x.509 v3 was considered for adoption (1995).

**Note:**

Formatting the data with a DER dumper (like in Crypt32's answer) or using openssl to display your certificate can give you the impression that all is decoded in one pass.

The way specification holes work, your tool decodes the **Certificate** first and gets bytes for each extensions (holes). Then, one at a time, you decode the bytes using the specification pointed to by **extnID** to get the value of the extensions.

Comment: I think I understand also your point, but what I feel is not being acknowledged really is that there is some redundancy there. Maybe I want to just use "some bytes" as extValue and put it in an OCTET_STRING, ok, but what will turn out in practice is actually OCTET_STRING<OCTET_STRING<bytes>>.
I think the best way to put my thoughts into "ASN.1" language is extValue could've also been maybe a `CHOICE` of all ASN.1 types, but maybe it's just simpler / cleaner to define it always as OCTET_STRING...

Comment: It could ... but it would mean that the x509 specification was also specifying the extensions ... which it does not.